# how to find visualforce page is added or not in pagelayout by Query

Tags: soql, query, page-layout

I have 100 objects and i need to find for each object and each page layout name if visual-force page is added to that page layout.
Is there any way to do this by querying.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use the ANT Migration Tool to pull down all the layouts using:

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>Layout</name>
</types>
```

This will give you an entire folder of .xml files containing the metadata for your layouts.
If there is a page layout with a Visualforce page embedded, you'll get a tag that looks something like this:

```
<layoutItems>
    <height>300</height>
    <page>VisualforcePageName</page>
    <showLabel>false</showLabel>
    <showScrollbars>false</showScrollbars>
    <width>100%</width>
</layoutItems>
```

The `<page>*</page>` attribute is key.

Comment: Thanks for reply.but the folder contains separate file for each page layout, So i guess it will take same time as manual activity .Is there any way to fetch all page layout of atleast one object at a time

Comment: If you use a text editor like SublimeText, you can search text within an entire folder. I like @Vamsi Krishna's answer. You can also use the Tooling API.  If you're looking for a SOQL Query, you're out of luck. You'll have to utilize one of the APIs that allows metadata access.

Answer (score 0):

Once option is to can use **Metadata API** (and its Apex wrapper if you are doing this in Apex) to get the list of **Layouts** and check the **LayoutItem** for the Layout.

If the **LayoutItem.page** has been set, then it refers to a visualforce page added to that page layout.